# Adding Azure AD member to a group calling Graph API shows bad request

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to call the Graph API to add a user to the Azure AD group, but it shows me a bad request.

I have the script and it looks for me that it should work, but it shows be a bad request. Other calls work perfect, and I have all the permissions in Azure AD for the app registration.

```
function AddUserToGroup {
    param (
        [string] $TenantId,
        [string] $GroupId,
        [string] $UserId,
        [string] $ClientId,
        [string] $ClientSecret
    )

    try {
        # Azure AD token endpoint
        $tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token"

        # Azure AD API endpoint to add members to the group
        $apiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$GroupId/members/$ref"

        # Request access token
        $tokenBody = @{
            client_id     = $ClientId
            client_secret = $ClientSecret
            grant_type    = "client_credentials"
            scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
        }

        $tokenResponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Body $tokenBody
        $accessToken = $tokenResponse.access_token

        # Construct the request body
        # Create the hashtable representing the JSON content
        $body = @{
            "@odata.id" = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/$userId"
        }

        $headers = @{
            Authorization  = "Bearer $accessToken"
            "Content-Type" = "application/json"
        }

        # Add the user to the group
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $apiEndpoint -Headers $headers -Body ($body | ConvertTo-Json)
        Write-Host "Added user with ID $UserId to the group."
    }
    catch {
        Write-Host "An error occurred while adding user with ID $UserId to the group: $($_.Exception.Message)"
        if ($_.Exception.Response) {
            $errorResponse = $_.Exception.Response.GetResponseStream()
            $reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($errorResponse)
            $reader.BaseStream.Position = 0
            $reader.DiscardBufferedData()
            $responseBody = $reader.ReadToEnd()
            Write-Host "Detailed error response: $responseBody"
        }
    }
    
}

# Usage:
$tenantId = ""
$groupId = ""
$userId = ""
$clientId = ""
$clientSecret = ""

AddUserToGroup -TenantId $tenantId -GroupId $groupId -UserId $userId -ClientId $clientId -ClientSecret $clientSecret
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out PowerShell is converting $ref to "", Always a bummer, seen and debugged many times. You script is okay.

Just replace the API Endpoint with something like below to preserve $ref in the Graph API endpoint called. Apparently single quotes will not try to treat $ref as a variable reference.

```
# Azure AD API endpoint to add members to the group

$apiEndpoint = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$GroupId/members/`$ref"
```

Comment: variable expansion can be escaped using a backtick, there is no need for the extra step

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I am no PowerShell expert, I tried `"/members/$\ref"` and `"members/\$ref"`, no worked. Please comment here how to escape the $ in $ref in a single line

Comment: like this: ``"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$GroupId/members/`$ref"`` the backtick before `$ref` escapes the variable expansion